# How to change text color of simple list item

Tags: android, listview

I have an ListActivity and i am displaying one list with:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, mStringList));
```

By default text color of list items is white, I want to change text color of text views in the list to black.

How should i do it?

Comment: You just need to set TextColor property of  TextView for changing font color.

Comment: I tried with creating new simple_list_item_single_choice_1.xml it works will for first tiem but then it segments when i re visit the activity.

Comment: In my opinion the best method is to use the method explained by Dharmin. That actually satisfies the question asked.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Another simplest way is to create a layout file containing the textview you want with textSize, textStyle, color etc preferred by you and then use it with the ArrayAdapter.

e.g. mytextview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:textColor="@color/font_content"
    android:padding="5sp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/rectgrad"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

and then use it with your ArrayAdapter as usual like

```
ListView lst = new ListView(context);
String[] arr = {"Item 1","Item 2"};
ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,R.layout.mytextview,arr);
lst.setAdapter(ad);
```

This way you won't need to create a custom adapter for it.

Comment: In which directory you would keep your resource file, mytextview.xml in this case

Comment: You can keep it in res > layout directory.

Comment: @dharmin007 but one issue is here its not coming with default checkbox we have to maintain our checkbox by ourself

Answer (score 52):

I realize this question is a bit old but here's a really simple solution that was missing.
**You don't need to create a custom ListView or even a custom layout.**

Just create an anonymous subclass of ArrayAdapter and override getView(). Let super.getView() handle all the heavy lifting. Since simple_list_item_1 is just a text view you can customize it (e.g. set textColor) and then return it.

Here's an example from one of my apps. I'm displaying a list of recent locations and I want all occurrences of "Current Location" to be blue and the rest white.

```
ListView listView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listView);
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, MobileMuni.getBookmarkStore().getRecentLocations()) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        String currentLocation = RouteFinderBookmarksActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.Current_Location);
        int textColor = textView.getText().toString().equals(currentLocation) ? R.color.holo_blue : R.color.text_color_btn_holo_dark;
        textView.setTextColor(RouteFinderBookmarksActivity.this.getResources().getColor(textColor));

        return textView;
    }
});
```

Comment: This answer is much better.

Comment: This takes away from the Model View Controller aspect of android. Something like color should be set up through the view. Keeping them separate creates cleaner code. Also, the templates android provides are just templates and meant to be replaced when your style changes.

Comment: Note: give this exact same override treatment to "getDropDownView" if you want to change just the dropdown (flyout) and not the base spinner.

Answer (score 39):

You just have override the `getView` method of `ArrayAdapter`

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), 
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mStringList) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        return view;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way to do this without needing to create anything extra would be to just modify the simple list `TextView`:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, strings) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                TextView textView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                textView.setTextColor({YourColorHere});
                return textView;
            }
        };
```

Comment: the get view method should return the rowView not the TextView :)

Comment: Perfect answer. Short and sweet.

Answer (score 4):

In simple word **"you can't do it through simple setListAdapter"** . you must used custom listview for freely changes in text color or in any other views

[for Custom Listview you can go with this link](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-part-1)

Answer (score 2):

you can use setTextColor(int) method or add style to change text color.

```
<style name="ReviewScreenKbbViewMoreStyle">
<item name="android:textColor">#2F2E86</item>
<item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
<item name="android:textSize">10dip</item>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm also faced this situation. You can handle above method. but simple if you pass 
simple_dropdown_item_1line as resource. It will be black color text by default.

This is my code I have achieved in kind of situation.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrAdapter = 
new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,countryList);
        listView.setAdapter(arrAdapter);
```

Your code below:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, mStringList));
```

Actually android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line is used for dropdown. I urge u to see this layout content once. It just simple textview. thats all. It's property will not affect your task. I checked It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in stead of `android.r.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice` create your own layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold">
</CheckedTextView>
```

Comment: how to apply custom checkbox android:checkMark ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep all the style but change few details, you can use the default style defined on the Android and change what you want

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />
```

Then set the adapter using:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
            R.layout.list_item_custom, mStringList));
```

Source: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_activated_1.xml

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a class that extends an Adapter, you can use parent variable to obtain the context.

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private Context context;
   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       context = parent.getContext();
       context.getResources().getColor(R.color.red);
       return convertView;
   }
}
```

You can do the same with RecyclerView.Adapter, but instead of getview() you will use onCreateViewHolder().

Answer (score 0):

Create an xml file in res/values and copy the below code

```
<style name="BlackText">
<item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
```

and the specify the style in activity in Manifest like below

```
 android:theme="@style/BlackText"
```

Comment: using this makes the dialog black, any suggestions to only make the text black?

Answer (score -1):

try this code...

```
<RelativeLayout 
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
         android:background="#ffff00"> 

    <ListView 
            android:id="@+id/android:list" 
            android:layout_marginTop="2px" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="2px" 
            android:layout_marginRight="2px"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:background="@drawable/shape_1" 
            android:listSelector="@drawable/shape_3" 
            android:textColor="#ffff00" 
            android:layout_marginBottom="44px" /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: this post is missing how what images are expected for 'shape_1' and 'shape_3'. also just setting the 'android:textColor' attribute doesn't change the list item text colors.