# text Color ArrayAdapter with simple_list_item_single_choice

Tags: android, android-listview, radio-button, android-arrayadapter

am creating a listView using array adapter. this is my code.

```
listView = new ListView(context);
                 ArrayAdapter<String>adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, choice);
                 listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

this provide a black color for text. i need to change the text color to blue color. how can we change this. i used my layout with array adapter. and this is the code

```
listView = new ListView(context);
                 ArrayAdapter<String>adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,layout.my_single_choice, choice);
                 listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and code for my_single_choice.xml is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RadioButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/my_choice_radio"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:button="@null"
    android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
    android:text="Option"
    style="@style/ListItemTextColor" />
```

and this doesn't work i can select all my radiobuttons. and when clickListener is not working,...? how can we solve it

Comment: have you tried with android:textColor ?

Comment: you should use a custom adapter for your listview. probably instead of radio button i think you need check boxes.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16685366/customised-listview-using-arrayadapter-class-in-android/16686623#16686623. and in checkbox.xml add text color as told by @blackbelt

Answer (score 4):

There are some approaches that could be done to use this. The most common ways of doing this are as following:

- Using a custom listview (http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-part-1)
- Using a custom layout (not inside the android.R namespace)

  In your view,  use this code:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/tv"
      android:textColor="@color/font_content"
      android:padding="5sp"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:background="@drawable/rectgrad"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
  ```

  In your class,  use this code:

  ```
  ListView lst = new ListView(context);
  String[] arr = {"Item 1","Item 2"};
  ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String (context,R.layout.mytextview,arr);
  lst.setAdapter(ad);
  ```
- My favorite, overriding the getView method of the ArrayAdapter

  ```
  ListView listView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listView);
  listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, MobileMuni.getBookmarkStore().getRecentLocations() ) {
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      TextView textView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

      String currentLocation = RouteFinderBookmarksActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.Current_Location);
      int textColor = textView.getText().toString().equals(currentLocation) ? R.color.holo_blue : R.color.text_color_btn_holo_dark;
      textView.setTextColor(RouteFinderBookmarksActivity.this.getResources().getColor(textColor));

      return textView;
      }
  });
  ```

Also, this was the result of a discussion from here: [How to change text color of simple list item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563698/how-to-change-text-color-of-simple-list-item)

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to keep it simple and don't want to add any new layout or files you can do something like this to change the color of `simple_list_item`s .

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, listItems) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            // Set the color here
            textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            return textView;
        }
    };
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

similar to what @priyankvex said, to answer OP's question, you can access to the `simple_list_item_single_choice` layout class by overriding the `getView` method, and change whatever property you want:

```
 listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, list) {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
                CheckedTextView view = (CheckedTextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                return view;
            }
        });
```