# Android SDK Issue setting/resetting ListView item background

Tags: android, listview, background

I wish to manually rearrange the order of a ListView.  The way I (want to) achieve this is by tapping on the item to be moved, setting the background of that item to a different colour, storing its position (oldPosition) and then tapping on the item which it is to appear below and finally resetting the background of the original item location.

The code I use to do this is:-

```
    List<String> catarray;            //  string array declared in main activity
    ArrayAdapter<String> catadapter;  //  adapter for Spinner declared in main activity
    ListView cats;                    //  listview declared in list activity
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;     //  adapter for listview declared in list activity
    int oldPosition = -1;

    cats.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (oldPosition < 0) {
                oldPosition = position;
                try {
                    dr = parent.getChildAt(position).getBackground();
                    parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, 0, 153, 204));
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
            else {
                String item = PhotoActivity.catarray.remove(oldPosition);
                PhotoActivity.catarray.add(position,item);
                try {
                    parent.getChildAt(oldPosition).setBackground(dr);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                }
                oldPosition = -1;
                changed = true;

                PhotoActivity.catadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
   });
```

The problem that I have is that if the list is larger than the displayed view then both the item that I tap on gets the background changed but so does an additional item that is below the visible range.

So, for example, if the full list is, say, 12 items long of which the first 8 are being displayed, if I tap on the second item then both that item but also item 11 (ie the second item plus one below the visible range) is highlighted.

1. Why does this happen?
2. How can I either stop it or, if I can't do that, reset the incorrectly highlighted item given that it is not visible and therefore not accessible via parent.getChildAt ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only answer I've found is to add a getView method for the adapter, call super.getView and then change the background colour there.

Also, you need to call view.setBackgroundColor in the OnItemClickListener event to make sure that the background is changed at the point of clicking.

So, my code ends up as being:-

```
    cats.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (oldPosition < 0) {
                oldPosition = position;
                try {
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, 0, 153, 204));
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
            else {
                String item = PhotoActivity.catarray.remove(oldPosition);
                PhotoActivity.catarray.add(position,item);
                oldPosition = -1;
                changed = true;

                PhotoActivity.catadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
   }); 

   adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(c, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, PhotoActivity.catarray) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            if (oldPosition> -1 && oldPosition==position) {
                textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, 0, 153, 204));
            }
            else {
                textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0));
            }
            return textView;
        }           
    };

    cats.setAdapter(adapter);
```

My thanks to Cameron Saul at SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563698/how-to-change-text-color-of-simple-list-item) for pointing me in the right direction.