# Trouble changing ListView Checkbox Style

Tags: android, listview

I am building my first app in Android and I have two problems using a ListView with checkbox integrated. I have the ListView working.

However, I was trying to change the style of the checkboxes for Material Design but with no sucess. I have the following code:

```
  <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="195dp"
            android:id="@+id/playerList"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
            style="@style/PlayerListStyle"/>


<style name="PlayerListStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ListView">
        <item name="android:background">@color/listViewBackground</item>
        <item name="android:divider">@color/listViewDivider</item>
        <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/listViewText</item>
        <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@color/listViewText</item>
        <item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.CheckBox</item>
    </style>
```

I have 19 min SDK Version, so I think I must use AppCompat.

The other problem is that I can't change the text color and I don't know why.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What adapter are you using for the ListView? If it's a custom adapter then you would change the text colour in the XML for the Listview's item (row) (colour would apply to all) or alternately in within the adapter's code (e.g. for Custom Cursor either in the bindView method or, if used in the getView method (getView is optional)) (using either of these you could have colours according to conditions). I've never really used Simple Adapters so I'm not sure about them. I can't help with checkbox styles.

Comment: I am using an ArrayAdapter.

Comment: This link should assist you with the text colour. [How to change text color of simple list item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563698/how-to-change-text-color-of-simple-list-item)

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of what you're seeing? As far as I remember you need to add a checkable textview(can't remember what it is exactly called) in the layout for each item of the listview.

Comment: And also add your list view row xml file

Comment: @MikeT I have tried the textColor but I have no idea why it doesn't work...

Comment: @AkashAggarwal Here you have the [link to the photo](http://imgur.com/KMeVrJX)
I did not understand what you said about textview. I have one listview with 2/3/4 elements, are you saying that I need 4 TextViews and make them visible or invisible?

Comment: Did you try declaring the style block before the listview block?

Comment: @AkashAggarwal the style is declared in styles.xml and the ListView is in the activity xml.