# MultiAutoCompleteTextView list items not showing text

Tags: android

I am developing an Android application and I've never worked with **MultiAutoCompleteTextView** before.

In my **layout.xml** I've added:

```
<MultiAutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/autocomplete_subtest"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="" />
```

And in my **DialogFragment**:

```
try {
  subtestAutoCompleteTextView = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_subtest);
  ArrayAdapter<String> subtestAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, subtests);

  subtestAutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(subtestAdapter);
  subtestAutoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1);
  subtestAutoCompleteTextView.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The items, however, appear with a transparent text:

[image]

If I click on the list item, with the empty text, it completes my MultiAutoCompleteTextView with an expected option.

Any idea why the text does not show on the item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the text color of list item. It`s may be white so change to black.

**EDIT 1**

Just to explain how to solve this, I followed this link: [How to change text color of simple list item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563698/how-to-change-text-color-of-simple-list-item)

Basically, create a custom layout.xml file with the TextView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:textColor="@color/font_content"
    android:padding="5sp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/rectgrad"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

And in my code I changed:

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> subtestAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.my_layout_file, subtests);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Change The ArrayAdapter, it will work 100%. I test it myself for you. use this

```
ArrayAdapter subtestAdapter = new  ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,subtests);
```

And subtests object to String Array. Like this

```
String [] subtests = {"Enamul","Ashraful", "Tonu", "Shawan","Morshed"};
```

If you initialize it from database or other place and use `ArrayList<String> subtests` like this. Then you can assign it to an `String Array` from `ArrayList`using 3 line of code like this

```
String [] subtests2 = new String[subtests.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < subtests.size(); i++) {
    subtests2[i]=subtests.get(i).toString();
}

ArrayAdapter subtestAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,subtests2);
```

Good Luck...

Answer (score 0):

```
<MultiAutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:cursorVisible="true"
            android:ellipsize="none"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:background="@null"
             />
```

Try this above code in your xml file.its working in my case.